# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS installation...hardware problem

Tags: 16.04, boot, system-installation, 18.04, system

I am using using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS  (with updates).

The processor is 1.60 GHz x 2.  Ram 2GB+1GB= 3GB. Hard Disk 1 TB.  OS type is 32-bit only.

I have  installation problem  with Ubuntu 18.04.  I could install it and open it once or twice with 2 GB RAM. Copying and Updating was also possible. But it is no longer working (not because of the additional RAM). The last stage is the problem. The mouse pointer gets stuck on the third dot seen just below "UBUNTU".  Log-in screen does not appear. No hard disk problem. I increased RAM by 1 GB (Now, total 3 GB).  This post is using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

My old LCD monitor is becoming white on 1/5 of the screen. [see EDIT]

Twice or thrice the following message appeared:

"The system is running in a low-graphic mode

Your screen, graphic card and input devise settings could not be detected correctly......"

But it is working without any problem of low-graphic mode. It is working in normal mode.

**Every time** I log-in,  the following window appears:

"System program problem detected

Do you want to report the problem now?"

But when I click on for report, no new window appears after entering my password.  But it doesn't create any problem. I have no other problem with 16.04.

Which part should I change before trying 18.04? Using Bootable USB, "Try Ubuntu" is working without problem.

I can't diagnose the problem clearly. Would it be because of my monitor?

[I could use 18.04 only after using GRUB, recovery mode etc.  Since there are no other OS, GRUB usually never appears even though I press Shift key.]

EDIT:

Now I have changed my old monitor. But still the two messages appears. One about the Graphic mode (rarely) and the other about system problem. The message about system problem appears every time I login. One more problem I detected: The name of the processor on the screen (all the words related while showing this name INTEL) is jerking. But this problem is seen only while showing that name.

Comment: What is your graphic card?

Comment: Intel® 945G x86/MMX/SSE2.   Intel Corporation 82945G/GZ Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02)

Please note: I have made a slight change in the question.

Comment: I believe, Processor, RAM, or Monitor is creating problem...sometimes two of  them. But can't diagnose the problem.

Comment: Is it possible to install 32bit still?? The discussion here is all about 32bit..ubuntu 18.04 LTS supports 32bit??

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 still supports 32-bit, but there is no longer an easy way to install it.